# Display Woocommerce Products as well as Magento Products on my core PHP site or CodeIgniter site

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, curl, woocommerce

Is it possible to display **wordpress woocommerce products** as well as **Magento products** on my **PHP site or CodeIgniter** site.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, It is possible to display products either from woocommerce or magento to your PHP site. If your site is on the same server then you have to make connection with database and fetch products and corresponding details using queries. If it is on another domain  then you have to use CURL. Create a script in PHP using which you can get products. **So my answer is Yes, you can fetch and display wordpress woocommerce products as well as magento products on your PHP site or codeigniter site.**

Comment: Yeah Its on another domain . Can you please share the link how to get data by using Curl. Thanks in Advance.